# Spring JPA postProcessBeforeDestruction being called on non-entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa

it's bit complex to describe the environment but I'll try my best.

I'm seeing no functional error, however I'm very concerned by an error I see in the logs after the spring context is being closed (it's a batch application which executes and then closes) as it's triggering some JPA destruction on an object which has nothing to do with JPA.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations.hashCode not implemented.
at net.mycompany.authenticationclient.RestOperationsWithAuthentication.invoke(RestOperationsWithAuthentication.java:29)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.hashCode(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(ConcurrentHashMap.java:333)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1175)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:238)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:540)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:824)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:485)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
```

There is some JPA configuration but it's listening on a different package:

```
<bean id="dashboard_entity_manager_factory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.mycompany.dashboard.domain" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="dashboard"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dashboard_connection_pool" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The invokation handler:

```
public class RestOperationsWithAuthentication implements InvocationHandler {

protected RestOperations restClient;
protected AuthenticationClient authClient;

protected boolean authenticated;

public RestOperationsWithAuthentication(RestOperations restClient, AuthenticationClient authClient) {
    this.restClient = restClient;
    this.authClient = authClient;
    this.authenticated = false;
}

@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] arguments) throws Throwable {
    if (arguments == null || !(arguments[0] instanceof String)) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method " + RestOperations.class.getCanonicalName() + "."
                + method.getName() + " not implemented.");
    }

    String url = arguments[0].toString();

    if (!authenticated) {
        authClient.authenticate(null);
        authenticated = true;
    }

    AuthenticationUrl<String> authUrl = authClient.addAuthParameters(url);
    arguments[0] = authUrl.getUrl();

    try {
        return invoke(method, arguments);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        if (e.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)) {
            authClient.authenticate(authUrl.getSessionToken());
            arguments[0] = authClient.addAuthParameters(url).getUrl();

            return invoke(method, arguments);
        }

        throw e;
    }
}

protected Object invoke(Method method, Object[] arguments) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return method.invoke(restClient, arguments);
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw e.getCause();
    }
}
```

}

And the creation of the object that matters is

```
<bean id="auth_http_client" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations" 
      factory-bean="auth_http_client_factory" factory-method="createRestClientWithAuthentication" />
```

Which is just a decorator over RestTemplate introducing some custom authentication layer over APIs. I tried declaring the class as RestTemplate but there was no difference.

Now in all cases, there is no functional issue, things work as expected, I am concerned as to why is some Spring JPA PostProcessor being hooked to some random bean. Is very edge case but it just beats me... I can't seem to properly follow what's going on.

Spring version is 4.0.2. I tried older versions, doesn't seem to make a difference.

My question is why is this happening and how can I avoid it?

Note, upon debugging I have found that seems all defined beans are being included in this ConcurrentHashMap. Perhaps an issue with mixing XML with annotations?

I have this in one of the xmls imported into the context:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="dashboard_transaction_manager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

But the beans being called in the Persistence Post Processor are not annotated with transactional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Javadoc of `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` or `PABPP`, and then at its source code. It contains a `ConcurrentHashMap` called `extendedEntityManagersToClose`. The keys of that map are the beans that **may** have had an `EntityManager` or `EntityManagerFactory` injected because of `PersistenceUnit` or `PersistenceContext` annotations.

Now `PABPP` implements `DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor`, so its `postProcessBeforeDestruction()` method is called during container destruction with **every** bean being destroyed. The implementation of this method calls `remove()` on the map, specifying the bean being destroyed as the key, **in case** there's an associated `EntityManager*`. Calling `ConcurrentHashMap.remove()` in turn calls `hashCode()` on the key, i.e. on every bean.

It blows up because when `hashCode()` is called via your `RestOperationsWithAuthentication.invoke()` it violates your guard clause which expects method arguments.

Comment: no, authentication is done via another web service, no JPA, JPA is for persisting status changes into the database, is not related with the http clients, I'll take a look about why it ended in a PersistenceContext, that appears to be what's happening

Comment: I added the invokation handler, it's not a traditional decorator, but sure, if that helps

Comment: Sorted it out, fixing answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is the Spring component that handles entity manager injection in Spring components. It targets components where the   `@PersistenceContext` annotation was applied.

When the Spring context is destroyed at job stop time, the post processor will clean a static cache that it holds of entity managers that are running in extended mode.

One way that `RestOperationsWithAuthentication` could have ended up in this cache is if an `EntityManager` is injected in that class, which should not be.

One solution and a best practice is not to inject entity managers only in the persistence layer, and not the web layer controllers or the persistence layer.

Also if the job is stopping and the JVM is being shutdown, you can safelly ignore this message. The only reason why the destroy method tries to clean the cache is to prevent memory leaks upon redeployment.

If during a redeployment the cache was kept populated, objects inside the class would reference via their class object the classloader, preventing the old version of the application from being garbage collected.

If the job halting does not mean that the JVM is shutdown, then this error is indeed something to worry about as it indicates a potencially big memory leak, where lots of classes of a previous version of the application are left hanging around.

Comment: This is not a web application, there's no controllers. I usually annotate only the DAOs unless I actually need the service layer to be annotated. As I said in the question, is a batch process, when it finishes I'm seeing this, I don't think there's a big problem, but it seems very odd. It could be that something which uses the auth client got annotated with @Transactional, I'm looking into that.

Comment: I know I can ignore it, I still don't want it there.

Comment: Are you sure that `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is related to `@Transactional`? I know that `SpringTransactionAnnotationProcessor` deals with `@Transactional`, I don't know how that connects to `PABPP`. The latter only directly refers to `@PersistenceContext` and `@PersistenceUnit`.